# Commandline gstreamer player

Tags: command-line

Is there a good, simple commandline player that uses gstreamer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gst123](http://freshmeat.net/projects/gst123) is command line music player that uses gstreamer. I have not messed with it, I generally use MOC.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use audiopreview.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't available back in 2010, but since GStreamer 1.2 ca. 2013, there is a utility called gst-play.  It is a simple utility that can play an individual audio file, or recurse through directories and play all the audio files it finds.  E.g. `gst-play-1.0 /path/to/media.mp3`.  See `man gst-play-1.0` for more information.  Also see `gst-play-1.0 --help` for other options that aren't in the man page (including playlist from file).  It's officially intended for "testing purposes".

Answer (score -1):

You can use gst-launch from gstreamer-tools.

```
man gst-launch
```

Comment: Except - you know - I don't want to construct pipeline each time I want to play something... (I was aware and I did used gst-launch).

Comment: Use playbin2, gst-launch playbin2 uri=file:///path/to/movie.avi suburi=file:///path/to/movie.srt

If you don't want to type the whole thing each time, you could just write a bash script.

Comment: But, I think keyboard shortcuts are not working when playing movies with gst-launch.

Comment: For good answer, you should also show examples in addition to pointing to further reading material. For example, if answer gives few examples, reader can immediately know if command is going to work.